# FB.getLoginStatus's callback isn't firing

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, sdk, webview

I have the following code in a script tag in my HTML page:

```
         window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            if (FB != null) {
                FB.init({
                    appId: 'myAppID',
                    status: true,
                    cookie: true,
                    xfbml: true,
                    oauth: true
                });

                FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                    console.log("callback");
                }, true);
            }
        };

        (function () {
            var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;

            var protocol = "http:";
            if (document.location.protocol == "https:")
                protocol = "https:";
            e.src = protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());
```

The page is loaded in an Android WebView from a domain matching the registered one in FB's app settings.

For no apparent reason, the callback no longer fires. It worked just yesterday, but today it doesn't work, *without me changing any code or app setting*.

I placed a console.log() call before the getLoginStatus call, and it seems that the call itself is reached and executed; also I can see that some files are loaded from static.ak.facebook.com. It's just that the callback isn't called.

The application is *not* in a Sandboxed mode, which seemed to have caused this behavior for others.

I should also mention that the same code works perfectly in a standalone browser (desktop & mobile).

What gives?

Comment: I too have the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364827/fb-getloginstatus-suddenly-stopped-working-on-android-browser

Comment: I reverted to the Facebook Android SDK after losing some of my last strands of hair.