# FB.getLoginStatus suddenly stopped working on android browser

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, facebook-javascript-sdk

I used to use this code:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
....
}
```

But all of a sudden its not working, The callback doesn't fire. Oddly though, only with the android native browser (tested 4.0, 4.1). It works on iPhone, iPad, Chrome & Safari, including Chrome for android. I can't figure out why but its not restricted to my app. For instance I this app built by Sencha is no longer working either (I used it to base my code off):

http://www.sencha.com/apps/jog-with-friends

actual app url (Sencha Jog with friends): http://j.mp/senchajwf

I have gone through a lot of posts on this issue and followed what they instruct but the jog with friends app is built well & includes for instance the `fbAsyncInit` which can also cause this, but it would cause it on all browsers.

How can I fix this? I'm thinking of just using my own node script to handle fb instead of the js-sdk.

Comment: Zynga is reporting the error now as well. FB has made it a High priority: [link](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/176760275805232)

Comment: Do you have the issue too, could you upvote it too? It looks like they're finally on it

Comment: Update: Facebook will release a fix on Tuesday 26 March [link](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/176760275805232?browse=search_513e5aa4e725a0135277100)

Comment: There is a fix. Why the bounty ?